# How to selectively reload a component on the forge app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, confluence, forge

Im passing the value from react component “A” to forge resolver, now we are performing operation on values and returning the updated value to react component “B”, but component “B” is not getting updated and not showing the updated value. So how to reload the component “B” after receiving the updated value.

How to refresh a particular component or div in a forge app.

Im passing the value from react component “A” to forge resolver, now we are performing operation on values and returning the updated value to react component “B”, but component “B” is not getting updated and not showing the updated value. So how to reload the component “B” after receiving the updated value.

How to refresh a particular component or div in a forge app.

How to refresh the component without refreshing the page when getting the updated values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When asking a question please make sure to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can see what you have tried and we can get a grasp of you component layout.